# Memory Leak after delete []

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

I am having a memory leak issue and I can't figure out what might be causing it. I have a struct that contains an array. I occasionally need to resize the array, so I create a new array that is double the length of the old array, and copy all of the old values. Then I delete the array with "delete [] array", and reassign the old array with the new array.

```cpp
struct Structure {
    double* array = new double[1]
    int capacity = 1;
}

void resize (Structure& structure) {
    double* array = new double[structure.capacity * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < structure.capacity; i++) {
        array[i] = structure.array[i];
    }
    delete [] structure.array;
    structure.array = array;
}
```

I expect the old array to be deallocated and replaced with the new array. Instead I get a memory leak error.

```
==91== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==91==    at 0x4C3089F: operator new[](unsigned long)
```

Comment: This code won't compile. Please post code that is correct and can compile

Comment: The code looks okay besides the fact that you don't update `capacity`.  Can you give us  a [mre] that causes the memory leak to trigger?

Comment: How do you know, that such error is coming from `resize`? If you don't `delete[]` the memory anywhere outside of `resize` - that may be the cause of the issue.

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't do `structure.capacity *= 2;` after `structure.array = array` so `capacity` will stay at `1` even though you've allocated 2 doubles.

Comment: Why are you trying to do what `std::vector` does already?  Also, you didn't post a `main` program showing how you use your class.

Comment: Ask yourself what happens to the *final* instance of `Structure` (wherever that is). We don't know (obviously, since you posted no [mcve]), but without proper destruction the last allocation (which is also the first allocation if a resize never happened) is blatantly leaked.

Comment: It's quite likely that the place that this memory is leaking is not shown in the code you've posted. As others have stated, the leak will happen when your struct gets destroyed. You have not included that location of your code with your question.

Answer (score 3):

Your struct is not following the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), in particular it is missing a destructor to `delete[]` the current `array` when the struct itself is destroyed:

```cpp
struct Structure {
    double* array = new double[1];
    int capacity = 1;

    ~Structure() { delete[] array; } // <-- add this!

    /* also, you should add these, too:
    Structure(const Structure &)
    Structure(Structure &&)
    Structure& operator=(const Structure &)
    Structure& operator=(Structure &&)
    */
};
```

You really should be using `std::vector<double>` instead of using `new[]` directly. `std::vector` handles everything you are trying to do manually, and does it safer than you are:

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct Structure {
    std::vector<double> array;

    Structure() : array(1) {}
};

void resize (Structure& structure) {
    structure.array.resize(structure.array.size() * 2);
}
```

Or:

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct Structure {
    std::vector<double> array;

    Structure() { array.reserve(1); }
};

void resize (Structure& structure) {
    structure.array.reserve(structure.array.capacity() * 2);
}
```

Depending on how you are actually using the `array`.